# How can I send data on a get and receive a return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have to send this data in a get request but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me?

```
const ROUTE = "public/v1/route";

export async function showRoute(
  flow: string,
  token: string
): Promise<RouteParams> {
  const response = await client.get(ROUTE);
  return response.data;
}
```

Comment: you can define a variable and put the returned value from your async function in it and then use the value in the variable wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` or `.then()` promise chaining:

```
import {showRoute} from './path-to-showRoute'

showRoute(/* params */).then(data => sendGetRequest(data))

//or

async function sendRouteInfo(){
  const routeData = await showRoute(/* params */)
  if (routeData) sendGetRequest(routeData)
}
```

PS: `sendGetRequest` is a mock function which simply sends a get request using `axios` or `fetch`

Comment: I did not understand sorry

I need to send this token and flow, can you show an example similar to my code?

Answer (score 0):

axios.get(`${URL}`)
.then(response => console.log(response.data)
.catch(err)=> console.log(err)

---

That is when you are using axios (npm i axios) then import it

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [Fetch-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch). For example,

```
const ROUTE = resourcePath + '?' + new URLSearchParams({ ...params })

fetch(ROUTE) // sends a GET request
  .then((res: Response) => res.json() as MyExpectedDataType) // parses JSON response content
  .then((data: MyExpectedDataType) => {
    // do something with data
  })
  .catch(err => {
  })

// or
async function showRoute(): Promise<Something> {
  try {
    const res: Response = await fetch(ROUTE)
    const data = await res.json() as MyExpectedDataType
    // do something with data
  }
  catch (err) {
  }
}
```

`fetch` returns a Promise type on which you can chain asynchronous callbacks using `.then` and handle errors with `.catch` and `.finally`. You can also pass request method, headers, body content etc. as an optional second argument to `fetch`, see the documentation.